# Created Date display blank in Infopath form

Tags: 2010, infopath, calculated-column

I am using InfoPath to create a custom form on the SP2010 list. There is a field call due date which I added as calculated Value Property  with formula addDays(Created, 14). This show blank in the form. Can you please correct me where I went wrong?

Comment: What is Created? inside addDays(Created,14)

Comment: Created is "Created Date"

Comment: Is "Created Date" a field in SP List? Can you make sure there is a value in "Created Date" by adding that field in your form? Also if your "Created Date" is actually current date then use addDays(today(), 14) instead

Comment: Yes. I have "created" field in SP list. Though it is not one of the column I added, it is out of box column that shows when the item is added. That created date is not the same as today's date. Items are added a week back todays date. I cannot use today() in addDays function as it returns the due date which is 2 weeks from todays date. Even if I use this today(), I am getting blank in SharePoint list for the due date column. Whenever, I created or update the list, the form show the date, however, it does not show the date in SP list.

Answer (score 0):

You are sure you opening an existing item?
Have you tried to put it directly in Data Source field of Calculated Value Properties?:

```
xdDate:AddDays(my:Created, 14)
```

This is working for me.